# While loop not repeating in c

Tags: c

I have to create a program that requests integer numbers from the user
repetitively though the keyboard  until the user enters 0. I've gotten to the while loop and its not repeating and I'm not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Edit: I've fixed the loop in terms of it not repeating but now it's infinitely repeating and I have no clue why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char first[30], last[30];
    int n, even, odd, etotal = 0, ototal = 0;

    printf("What is your first name?\n");
    scanf("%s", &first);
    printf("What is your last name?\n");
    scanf("%s", &last);
    // asks for name
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    printf("To quit the program enter 0\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n!=0){

        if(n%2==0){
            printf("%d is even.\n",n);
            etotal++;   }
        else{
            printf("%d is odd.\n",n);
            ototal++;   }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would have helped if you had stepped through this code with your debugger.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: `return 0` is part of the `while()` loop. Please remove it. It's not looping because it returns after the first iteration...

Answer (score 6):

The loop isn't repeating because you have a `return` statement in the loop, that will leave the `main` function immediately. Just remove it.

---

You also have another problem that's much worse: *Undefined behavior*. Local non-static variables, like for example `n` in your code, don't get initialized, instead they have an *indeterminate* value. Attempting to use such an uninitialized variable leads to said undefined behavior.

You need to explicitly initialize the variable to some value before using it in the condition, for example to reorder the code so you read input before the loop and then also at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Local variable n is uninitialized producing undefined results collaboratively called *undefined behavior*. Initialize it before entering loop:

```
n = 1;
```

And check result of scanf:

```
if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
    // error
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop is not working because you didn't initialize `n` and unnecessary return 0 inside the while loop. You can fix it with `do..while` as below. Because you have the input statement as your first statement, do..while is best opted here.

```
do{
  scanf("%d", &n);  
  if(n%2==0){
   printf("%d is even.\n",n);
   etotal++;   
  }
  else {
   printf("%d is odd.\n",n);
   ototal++;   
  }
} while (n!=0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because n is not initialized, so it has a random value:

```
int n, even, odd, etotal, ototal;
/* ... */
while (n!=0){
```

Answer (score 0):

You use scanf to read your input, but after your if/else statement you are returning 0 hence you are leaving the program. So it doesnt matter if you write an even or an odd number.

```
while (n!=0){
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n%2==0){
        printf("%d is even.\n",n);
        etotal++;   }

    else{
        printf("%d is odd.\n",n);
        ototal++;   
    }
return 0;
}
```